# make input button open fancybox

Tags: jquery, input, fancybox, href

Trying to launch fancybox through submit button.

**HTML:**

```
   <input id="test" type="image" src="image.png" value="url.php?id=1">
```

**JS:**

```
$('#test').click(function(makeFB){
    makeFB.preventDefault();
    var fbUrl = $(this).attr('value');
    var thisClick = $('a').attr('href', fbUrl);
    thisClick.addClass('fancybox-button');
    thisClick.click();
});
```

**RESULT:**

Opens up the URL in the active window. I need to initiate the fancybox popup through an input image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind fancybox to any element other than the `<a>` tag.

If you are using fancybox v2.x, then you can pass the `href` and `type` of content through the special (HTML5) `data-fancybox-*` attributes like :

```
<input class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" data-fancybox-href="url.php?id=1" type="image" src="image.png" />

<input class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="image" data-fancybox-href="images/image01.jpg" type="image" src="image.png" />
```

Notice that both buttons in the example above share the same *class* so you can use the same script for several elements. Also, each of them is set for a different `type` of content.

Then use this simple js code

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5gTrs/)**